# Is "What is confusing or unclear about this wording" a proper question for rpg.se?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'm building a homebrew magic item and I know the wording could be improved, but I need more eyes because things are clearer to me by nature of me knowing the intent. Is this appropriate for RPG.SE or should I head to the forums and chats?

(Here's my question on RPG.SE: [What is unclear about this homebrew magic item description?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126157/what-is-unclear-about-this-homebrew-magic-item-description))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Requesting feedback on your wording is viable, but asking it like that will not be.

First, it's a survey of individual reactions, not a question with a single best or correct answer. No response by anyone pointing out they found something confusing will be better or more correct than any other response.

More direly though, it won't get you the feedback you need: what if nothing at all is confusing, and it looks perfectly clear, but isn't remotely communicating what you want it to say? (Which happens all the time in the industry.)

Instead, show us the text, tell us what it *should* be doing that you're unsure that you're communicating clearly, and ask if the text you wrote expresses that clearly. That way we can tell you whether it does or doesn't, and whether it's being confusing in the process.

Please also see: [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question)

Comment: May be worth adding [this recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127297/41726) to your answer which follows your advice for a good wording question. Bit of irony that it showed up so close to the inquiry.

Answer (score 3):

## Potentially Stackable...but probably not.

While writing clarity may generally fit better on Writing.stackexchange.com, but given the specific use of wanting/needing a clear and concise description for RPGs, then the audience on our stack seems like a legitimate one.

### Homebrew review vs language review

If it is legitimate for this stack, and if you do post it, then I would also suggest being abundantly clear in your question that you are NOT looking for homebrew review but only in clarity of language.

## Upon further review - Primarily Opinion-based

After [seeing the Q&As so far](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126157/what-is-unclear-about-this-homebrew-magic-item-description) I'm rethinking my initial reaction. I'm not sure how you can determine which answer is correct and the resulting answers will only be Opinion-Based. I'm not sure there is a way to not only get "objective" answers, but a way to determine which of the answers is best.