# What's a good place to get feedback on / iron out a homebrew's balance?

Tags: discussion, homebrew

I don't think it's really a subject for the main questions area, it's too subjective and discussion drive. Open a chat? But how would poeple find that?

Comment: Alternately to a forum, you *can* ask us for feedback on homebrew, but we use an iterative process rather than a back-and-forth discussion process: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question

Comment: I strongly recommend [this one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5450/41726) from the Duplicate question. I've had great experiences there and it is often a good place to find people experienced in a wide variety of systems. From there, you can always ask people to join you in a separate chat room for more detailed analysis of a homebrew.