# How to follow-up with updated versions of homebrew content?

Tags: discussion, homebrew

I've been noticing questions and answers regarding homebrew content offer a lot of insight in understanding and designing features for the games I play (as GM and PC), like this recent one: [How might this homebrew undead hybrid character type unbalance combat compared to non-undead creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144855/42805)

After reading and incorporating feedback from the community, I'd like to share the result of the interaction. I'm thinking of two cases:

- **Case 1.** Further tweaking of the content, as if it is a second round of iteration. This would be work-in-progress.
- **Case 2.** Possibly inspiring (or getting inspired by) other people with similar questions and/or ideas. This would be a final result of the homebrew content.

**How to follow-up with updated versions of homebrew content?**

Let's use the linked question as an example:

1. Do I edit the question to include the updated content (like a next version, under the original version)?
2. Do I ask an entirely new question with the updated content?
3. Do I use another feature of this platform (of which I'm yet unaware)?
4. Or is this platform actually not suited for such feedback cycles and iterative design?

Ideally an answer to my question covers both cases and shows me relevant policies (or etiquette) when dealing with iterative design of homebrew content on this platform. I'm not interested in opinions on the matter.

Comment: To seem slightly less rude than my first comment. It belongs on meta because it is asking about how to use the site, that is exactly what meta is for. It isn't a bad question but has been asked before. If there are parts of that meta which don't answer your question you can open a new related question on meta to ask for further clarification.

Comment: No need for excuses, no offense taken at all! Your comment is perfect and has lead me to the information I'm seeking. I do appreciate the considerate follow-up though. :)

Comment: Related: [For iterated homebrew questions, should earlier iterations be marked as duplicates of later iterations?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8509/for-iterated-homebrew-questions-should-earlier-iterations-be-marked-as-duplicat), [Can we develop a system to avoid/discourage subsequent homebrew critique question edits?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/can-we-develop-a-system-to-avoid-discourage-subsequent-homebrew-critique-questio)

Comment: This is covered by section 2 of the duplicate target; it is option 2 on your list. Thanks for asking about this. Is there more you want to know or does that cover it?

Comment: @doppelgreener All the linked questions and answer are clear enough for me. Thanks!