# I'm designing a simple one-session RPG specifically to get beginners interested. Can I get feedback on the main site?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm designing a simple one-session RPG specifically to get beginners interested but with the opportunity for expansion. Can I get feedback for the basic version on the main site?

I have a number of simple rules for setup, equipment and gameplay. I would like to set them out and ask for feedback about any flaws that I may have missed or any additions I need to make.

Can I ask for that feedback on the main site? If so, what are my tags?

Comment: If you drop by [chat], you may have a chance to discuss with a few of our members who have written RPGs of the scale that you are attempting.  @BESW is one of them.  Time zones may be an issue, though.  Provide them a link to your draft system and ask them to comment.

Answer (score 13):

Mainsite isn't well suited to general feedback. We have a class of questions which are Reviews. Most of the guidance we have around it is geared at homebrew review,<sup>†</sup> as that is the question type we get the most and which mostly works on the site. What's needed for them to work, is clearly defined goals which expertise can discern whether is fulfilled.

This is where, I think, the type of feedback you're looking for comes in. There are probably good questions which can be constructed around the goals of your system, but it's gonna be virtually impossible to answer without experience with the system (or a *lot* of expertise with similar systems). I'm not sure the effort (and likely unanswered question) will be worth it to you.

For general (less qualified) feedback, you want a space closer to traditional forums. We maintain a list of RPG forums [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) and we also have [our own general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat). Among other topics, sharing, chatting, and giving feedback on creations is certainly supported in there.

---

†: See [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/52137)